# Store does not have a valid Reducer - How to pass a combined reducer into store?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to get my head around Redux and other answers are making it more of an obstacle at this point.

**reducers/index.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import photoInputPost from './photoInputPost'
import cameraInputPost from './cameraInputPost'
import textInputPost from './textInputPost'

export default rootReducer = combineReducers({
    photoInputPost,
    textInputPost,
    cameraInputPost
})
```

**store/index.js:**

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import reducer from './../reducers/index'

export default Store = createStore(reducer)
```

One of the reducers, **textInputPost.js**

```
const textInputReducer = (initialState, action) => {
    console.log('textInputReducer', action);
    switch(action.type){
        case 'ADD_INPUT_TEXT':
            return { textInputValue: action.text };
    default:
        return state;
    }
}
```

Not really sure what's going wrong but I'm probably passing the combined reducer in the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `rootReducer` file as:

```js
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import reducer1 from "./reducer1";
import reducer2 from "./reducer2";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({ reducer1, reducer2 });

export default rootReducer;
```

...and in your `index.js`, add this `rootReducer` as:

```js
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import rootReducer from "./reducers/rootReducer";

import App from "./components/app";
import React from "react";
import ReactDom from "react-dom";

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```